# Read/download part of file from google cloud storage in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I have a file on google cloud storage, that is quite big (10GB). I know exatly which bytes contain the information I need. Is there any way to read only these bytes using the google cloud java library without downloading the whole file?

Comment: See the function called DownloadByteRange in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/QuickStart/Program.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a range read: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/parameters#range

Comment: I hoped they provide a simple method in their api, I found some way to do it, but unfortunately there is a [bug, that won't be fixed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/290), so this is probably the only way, thanks.